# Get data from a mysql database and save it again with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to save in a database, data fetched from an `API`. In fact, I get from the API the sales numbers of products on sale on my site and I want to save them in my database via `ajax`. The problem is that I still have a lot of trouble with Javascript in general. So this is what I did.

I created a first file to save the data with ajax (I think that this is certainly the problem lol).

```
//script.js

function saving_data()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch.php",
            method:"POST",
            data : data,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function (stats) {
                jQuery.each(stats, function(i, val) {
                    var action = 'action';
                    var id = val["id"];
                    var sales = val["quantite"];
                    $.ajax({
                    url:"save.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{action:action, id:id, sales:sales}
                    });
                });
            },
            error : function () {
            alert("error");
            }
        });
    };
    
    saving_data();
        
    setInterval(function(){
        saving_data();
    }, 5000);
```

Then I have created a second file that allows me to fetch products from my database.

```
//fetch.php

$pdo = Connexion::getPDO(); // a PDO instance

$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date DESC");
$beats = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stats = [];

foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
    $salesstats = $api->sales(api-request);
    $stats[$key] = [
        "id" => $product["id"],
        "quantity" => $salesstats["quantity"], //get from api
        "amount" => $salesstats["amount"] // get from api
    ];
}

echo json_encode($stats);
```

At last I created a javascript file which should allow me to save the data in my database.

```
//save.php

$pdo = Connexion::getPDO(); // a PDO instance

if(isset($_POST['action'])){

    $bId = $_POST["id"];
    $bSales = $_POST["sales"];
    $update_query = "UPDATE products SET sales = '$bSales' WHERE id = '$bId'";
    $pdo->query($update_query);

}
```

Of course, it doesn't work. The database is not updated. But I can't work out what's wrong. Can someone please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: You pasted lots of code, both server and client side without any indication of the actual error and where that may be. You really should narrow the problem down.

Comment: The problem is simple, the database is not updated. No errors are displayed. I explained it at the beginning of my post. And I pasted the codes because sometimes people come and ask for the codes in detail.

Comment: You do not even connect to the database in save.php and there is absolutely no error handing or displaying of any errors in your code. So, you need to do some debugging first.

Comment: I connected. I just didn't put it in because I put it once in the previous code. All I want to know is, do you see an error in my codes?

Comment: How would we know that you deliberatly omitted certain parts of the code vs it is a genuine error?

Comment: @Shadow Okay, I've updated it

Comment: Okay, so what about the error handling and debugging part then?

Comment: Solved! Thanks @CBroe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the Ajax script. I specified a data parameter which is not defined. I thought that it was necessary to put it so that Ajax gets it back with the URL parameter file, but no, it was not necessary to put anything.

To check the error, I debugged the code in the browser's debugger, with the breakpoint method on ajax requests (The method is explained [here](https://christianelagace.com/php/comment-deboguer-une-requete-ajax/), but in French). The first one did stop the code, but not the second one. And the Firefox debugger clearly showed me the undefined data parameter (Chrome didn't do it).

[image]

So I deleted it and everything works.

Thanks to @CBroe for getting me on my way with their comment.